# global variable undefined but inside a function is defined

Tags: javascript, frontend

Hi guys this is my first question here, I'm new to front end and have a quick question,

I'm building an ATM website and this is a part of the js code, the variable `saldoUsuario` is in a global scope and whenever I use it inside a function for example in `saldoAlDia` it has a value, but when i `console.log` it outside de function is `undefined`.

```
let saldoUsuario;

function saldoAlDia(user) {

  const name = cuentas.map( function(cuenta) {
    return [cuenta.nombre, cuenta.saldo]
  })
  
  for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    if (user === name[i][0]) {
       saldoUsuario = name[i][1]  // has a value
    }
  }

  usBalance.innerHTML = saldoUsuario
  return usBalance.innerHTML = saldoUsuario // has a value
}

console.log(saldoUsuario) //undefined
```

I was trying to get saldoUsuario to work on the next function with its new value that was given in saldoAlDia function but didn't work since it's undefined

Comment: Global scope is a function itself, after `let saldoUsuario;`, the JS engine treats `function saldoAlDia(user) ..` as a declaration, then it immediately runs `console.log(saldoUsuario)` which is **before** you've run `saldoAlDia`.

Comment: Do you think that defining a function somehow automatically runs it? Do you think the statement `console.log(saldoUsuario);` is somehow connected to `saldoAlDia` and _waits_ until _something_ calls the function? Why?

Answer (score 2):

You have to run the function before `saldoUsario` has a value. Once you run it, it does:

```js
let saldoUsuario;

const cuentas = [{nombre: 'test', saldo: 12}, {nombre: 'test2', saldo: 14}];

function saldoAlDia (user){
  const name = cuentas.map(function(cuenta){
    return [cuenta.nombre, cuenta.saldo]
  })
  for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
    if(user === name[i][0]){
       saldoUsuario = name[i][1]  // has a value
    }
  }
  usBalance.innerHTML = saldoUsuario
  return usBalance.innerHTML = saldoUsuario // has a value
}

saldoAlDia('test');

console.log(saldoUsuario) //12

saldoAlDia('test2');

console.log(saldoUsuario) //14
```

```html
<div id="usBalance"/>
```